# Sorting and finding duplicates in excel columns

Tags: excel

I have five columns in my spreadsheet, three of which are filled with assorted names( the first, fourth and fifth columns).

[image: Excel spreadsheet]

I need a way to cross-reference each cell in the A column with the D and E columns, then have an output that answers the question in the B and C column (which you can see as the Xs), as to whether it was found. I've tried a combination of VLOOKUP and MATCH, but this is proving to be out of my realm. I haven't used excel much lately.

EDIT: Added a picture instead of a diagram

Comment: Use [countif()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34), so if it is greater than 0 it exists in the column.

Comment: @ScottCraner Do you ever have any work??? I want your job :_;

Comment: I looked into countif() and it doesn't sen to be what I want

Comment: If a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) didn't work, then you are doing it wrong. Show what you tried and we can clean it up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cell `B3` use `=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D,A:A),"","X")`

and in `C3` use `=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D,A:A),"","X")`

copy down as far as required

Formula says *"If count of names in `D:D` equal to name in current row in `A:A` is > 0 then return blank, else return "X"*

Test is case-insensitive.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this worked beautifully! Thank you! Also thank you @Scott Craner :)